# Match messages from WhatsApp log in python

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to extract all patterns that are matching a message in WhatsApp. The messages have the following form:

One line message:

```
[19.09.17, 19:54:48] Marc: If the mean is not in the thousands, there's the problem
```

Multiple line long message:

```
[19.09.17, 19:54:59] Joe: > mean(aging$Population)
[1] 1593.577
Is what I get as solution
```

I was able to split it into Date, Time, Sender and Message but only for one-liners by first reading in the text-file line for line and then splitting those lines on the different seperators. 
However that does not work for messages with multiple lines. Now I'm trying to use regular expressions, with which I was able to get the dates and times but I am still struggling to extend the pattern for messages to multiple lines.

```
## reg expressions to match different things in the log
date = r'\[\d+\.\d+\.\d+,'
time = r'\d+\:\d+\:\d+]'
message = r':\s+.+\['
message = re.compile(message, re.DOTALL)
```

Please note that my log is from German WhatsApp, which is why the dates are a bit different. Also I ended on the , and ] to make sure I don't accidentally get matches from within messages.

I would like to do the same with the message pattern by ending on a [ which is usually the start of the next line (but might not be really robust if that can be found in a message on a new line).

There is probably a way easier solution but I am (as you can see) really bad with regex.

Comment: This question is not answerable right now, unless the reader happens to know exactly what your WhatsApp text looks like (which you should not be assuming).  Please show us examples of both a single line WhatsApp message and a multi-line message.

Comment: Sorry! Completely forgot. Now added examples!

Comment: What is your expected output here?  What do you want to do with information?  Write to a log/table somewhere?  Something else?

Comment: The final output would be a data frame with the columns

date, time, sender, message

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general regex and solution using `re.findall`:

```
msg = "[19.09.17, 19:54:48] Marc: If the mean is not in the thousands, there's the problem
    [19.09.17, 19:54:59] Joe: > mean(aging$Population)
    [1] 1593.577\nIs what I get as solution"

results = re.findall(r"\[(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}), (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\] ([^:]+): (.*?)(?=\[\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}, \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\]|$)", msg, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

for item in results:
    print "date: " + item[0]
    print "time: " + item[1]
    print "sender: " + item[2]
    print "message: " + item[3]

date: 19.09.17
time: 19:54:48
sender: Marc
message: If the mean is not in the thousands, there's the problem
date: 19.09.17
time: 19:54:59
sender: Joe
message: > mean(aging$Population)
```

The pattern, which appears long and bloated, just matches the structure of your expected WhatsApp message.  Of note, the pattern uses both multiline and DOT ALL mode.  This is needed for messages which may span across multiple lines.  The pattern stops consuming a given message when either it sees the start of the next message (in particular, the timestamp), or it sees the end of the input.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
However the last message would not be complete, which was exactly the problem I had before. It doesn't take the second and third line in it as well.
Right now it just gives back '>mean(aging$Population' and cuts off what follows. Even if I use something easier than the [1]... line.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem.  My answer works for 2 lines, but are you saying it does not work for 3 lines?

Comment: In your solution for the multiple line message it gives out:

message: > mean(aging$Population)

The message was three lines long though. 
"[1] 1593.577
Is what I get as solution"
is missing there. 
Sorry if I'm being dumb, but when I try it out in my own notebook, it also just catches the first line of the message.

Comment: Setup a demo and paste the link here.

Comment: Demo: https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/3c578619-d94a-4d40-82ab-b74ff06dab89/?i=true
Problem: It only matches the first line of the message. I can't make it work that it saves all the lines in the results object.

Comment: @Nickfis I checked your demo, and I don't understand what the perceived problem is.  If you want to output the entire row, then just use `print(results[0])`.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's probably me not wording it well. Sorry for taking up so much of your time, but the problem is that the message itself has multiple rows. I want all saved into one message. Right now it only outputs ' > mean(aging$Population)', but line 2 and 3 of that message: 
        [1] 1593.577
        Is what I get as solution

are not included. I also updated the demo to make it a bit clearer there!

Comment: Please paste the new demo link and I will have a look.

Comment: Same link!
https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/3c578619-d94a-4d40-82ab-b74ff06dab89/?i=true

Answer (score 0):

Hijacking the above, to match in case of multline, I just croped the regex from Tim Biegeleisen

```
results = re.findall(r"\[(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}), (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\] ([^:]+): (.*?)(?=\[\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}, \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\])", msg, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```